# Use GROUP_CONTACT result as normal php code or string

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, concatenation, group-concat

I am not sure if this is working. Im trying to use the result from concat as normal php code. But I am getting plain text result. This is my code:
Query 1:

```
$resultdc = $wpdb->get_row($wpdb->prepare("SELECT user_id, goals_date, YEAR(goals_date) AS yearof, DATE_SUB(DATE(goals_date), INTERVAL DAYOFWEEK(goals_date) -1 DAY) AS weekof, TIME_FORMAT(SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(end_time))-SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(start_time))), '%H:%i') AS st_time, SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(end_time)-TIME_TO_SEC(start_time)) AS ltime, $sumleads $sumgoals FROM $table WHERE user_id IN($members) AND DATE_SUB(DATE(goals_date), INTERVAL DAYOFWEEK(goals_date) -1 DAY) = DATE_SUB(DATE('$goals_date'), INTERVAL DAYOFWEEK('$goals_date') -1 DAY) GROUP BY weekof"));
```

Query 2:

```
$dcharts = $wpdb->get_row($wpdb->prepare("SELECT GROUP_CONCAT('[\"',goalname,' - \'.\$resultdc->LT',goal_id,'.\'\", \'.\$resultdc->LT',goal_id,'.\']') AS dchart FROM wpgetyp_ppi_goalsettings WHERE user_id = '$head' AND goaltype ='leadtype' GROUP BY user_id"));
```

Result:

```
["Expired - '.$resultdc->LT1.'", '.$resultdc->LT1.'],["FSBOs - '.$resultdc->LT2.'", '.$resultdc->LT2.'],["Buyers - '.$resultdc->LT3.'", '.$resultdc->LT3.'],["Agent - '.$resultdc->LT4.'", '.$resultdc->LT4.'],["Followup - '.$resultdc->LT5.'", '.$resultdc->LT5.'],["Circle Marketing - '.$resultdc->LT6.'", '.$resultdc->LT6.'],["Door Knocking - '.$resultdc->LT21.'", '.$resultdc->LT21.']
```

I want to display result of **$resultdc->*** from first query. Or any better idea. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

The fact that there are dollar-signs in your results means that your quoting is not right. Try using:

```
"SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(
          '[',
          goalname,
          ' - {$resultdc->LT}', 
          goal_id,
          '{$resultdc->LT}',
          goal_id,']') AS dchart 
FROM      wpgetyp_ppi_goalsettings 
WHERE     user_id = '{$head}' 
      AND goaltype ='leadtype' 
GROUP BY  user_id"
```

as sql-statement

Comment: sorry but not working i dont get the value of $resultdc->LT1 as $resultdc->LT', goal_id,

Comment: what is the value of $resultdc ... using:
var_dump($resultdc)